# Migrating SQLite Data with FMDB into Core Data and iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, icloud

I'm pulling records out of SQLite with FMDB and adding them to Core Data, which is configured to sync with iCloud. This works fine for small numbers of data, but when thousands of records are being migrated, I'm getting memory warnings with crashes:

> Received memory warning.

...and iCloud sync errors:

> CoreData: iCloud: Error: failed to receive initial sync notification call back in 90 seconds

I'm trying to optimize the migration so that I don't run out of memory. I have read [Reducing Memory Overhead](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW4) but I don't understand much of it.

Here's my code, run in a background thread:

```
FMDatabaseQueue *queueOld = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:oldDatabasePath];

[queueOld inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *dbqOld, BOOL *rollback) {

  //(1) Query that extracts the aircraft data from the old database
  FMResultSet *aircraftResults = [dbqOld executeQuery:@"<SELECT ALL THE RECORDS...>"];

  //(2) Walk through each row returned from the database
  while ([aircraftResults next]){

    //(3) Create a new Core Data Aircraft NSManagedObject
    Aircraft *aircraft = [[PPCoreData myCoreData] createEntity:@"Aircraft"];

    aircraft.aircraftRegistration = [aircraftResults stringForColumn:@"aircraftRegistration"];
    aircraft.makeModel = [aircraftResults stringForColumn:@"aircraftMakeModel"];
    //etc...  
  }

  [aircraftResults close];
}];

//(4) Save to Core Data
[[PPCoreData myCoreData] save]; //"myCoreData" is a singleton that has all my Core Data goods
```

Should I save to Core Data more often? Would that keep my memory usage down?

Is there something else I can do to make this more memory efficient?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As with any high memory usage situation, you should profile using the Allocations instrument in Instruments to find out what is actually causing the high memory usage. Only then can you (or anyone) really say with certainty what a good possible solution is. Have you done that?

Comment: I ran an Allocations test in Instruments during the part of the app that has the issues. I'm unsure how to interpret the results, though. Here's a screenshot of the allocations: http://d.pr/i/15qzM